# Roblox Studio - Random Errors that i can't understand i get

Tags: lua, roblox

As you can see on the picture below I'm getting some errors in my code:

[image: Screenshot]

I have no clue why I'm getting these errors or what they mean and while they don't seem to do anything bad I would rather be able to get rid of them. So I'm asking if someone can tell me what they mean and how I would go around stopping them.

Here are the errors that are shown in the picture:

> 02:28:40.947 - Roact is not a valid member of CorePackages
>
> 02:28:40.949 - Requested module experienced an error while loading
>
> 02:28:40.950 - Requested module experienced an error while loading
>
> 02:28:40.953 - LocalizationPlugin is not a valid member of CorePackages
>
> 02:28:40.981 - LocalizationPlugin is not a valid member of CorePackages

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question has no code, no error, no desired outcome, ...  also upload your image in the question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are from scripts that are part of Roblox itself - you have no control over them and it's **normal** for them to have errors sometimes. Just ignore them.

Comment: @AsbjørnBonde they may be running a different version of Roblox Studio or they haven't called the same built in functions and features as you have.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting these errors is because of the Roblox application you're using is using the same Lua engine Roblox uses to code their back-end. Basically, these errors are squawked out by the engine because of errors in Roblox's code. Now you can't fix this, but it doesn't really matter. To be honest, most of them just look like warnings, nothing to worry about. If you use Chrome Dev Tools on most websites you'll see console errors or warnings. They're nothing to worry about if they don't affect the functionality.

Edit: Other people might not get these errors as they may have a different version of the Roblox Lua Engine or their hardware/software may communicate better compared to yours.